# How we are able to see stars in night, even if they are light years away from earth?

Tags: astronomy, speed-of-light

I am wondering, how we are able to see so much stars in the sky even though they are light years away from us. Even light take years to reach from those stars to earth? Then, how we are seeing those stars?

Comment: Why do you think that a long journey time here has an effect on our ability to see the stars?

Comment: Because they are *very* luminous. Can you not imagine how bright the Sun would be if it were many light years away?

Answer (score 0):

If  a star is, say, 4 light years away (eg alpha centauri), light from it takes 4 years to reach us. Stars are generally very bright, so they can be seen seen a long way away. That's all.

Comment: and of course the star what emitting before and after: star lifespan is long !

Comment: @Dr Chuck The images we see are made up of light reflected from the objects we look at.Am i right? So that light need to be here. right?

Comment: @J.Joseph In this case, the images are made of light *emitted* by the stars, not reflected.

Comment: @HDE226868 do you agree with anna v ?

Comment: @J.Joseph Both answers seem to be correct, yes.

Comment: @HDE226868 " In this case, the images are made of light emitted by the stars, not reflected."  Light emitted by the stars should reach our eyes in order to see it. Which will take light years. That's my question.

Comment: @J.Joseph *What* is the question? Yes, it takes light time to reach our eyes. I don't know what's confusing about that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31009/discussion-between-j-joseph-and-hde-226868).

Answer (score 0):

We are not seeing those stars as they are now. They may have disappeared in our now, for all we can know but earth will not become aware of that unless the appropriate light years have passed.

This is due to the fixed velocity of light, which we use as a measure of cosmic distances. The sun for example is 8 light minutes away from earth. If some cosmic disaster happens to it, we will know it 8 minutes later, not directly.

Comment: which means,some of those stars we see at night may be dead stars as of now? But we are seeing the light produced by it millions of light years back?

Comment: @J.Joseph - not quite. The most distant individual stars you can see with your eye are a few 1000lyr away.

Comment: @J.Joseph Yes, it happens with the superNova https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supernova explosions astronomers see , it is the death of a star that happened light years ago.

Comment: No star you can see with your naked eye (except perhaps the remote possibility of Betelgeuse) has died while the light has been travelling to us.